# iOS Build Fails With Error MT0018 When Paired to Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I have a Mac Mini, I paired it with Visual Studio on Windows and when I run the Build command the following errors appear? I didn't find any solution on the internet. Would anyone know how to solve it?

error MT0018: Unknown command line argument: '--reference=/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'

[image]
[image]

Comment: please do NOT post errors as screenshots!!

Comment: sorry,I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/186179/unknown-command-line-argument-reference-library-frameworks-xamarin-ios-framework

Comment: Read "Getting Started" at following : https://github.com/uikit/uikit

Comment: Update VS and Xcode on mac and try again.

Comment: @GabrielG.Pavan what works for you? Updating VS and XCode?